# What API Permissions are needed for Remove-AzureADUser?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I need to delete AAD guest users using powershell - where the script authenticates using certificate credential corresponding to a registered app. What API permissions does the registered app need?

```bsh
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId -ApplicationId $ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $CertificateThumbprint
Remove-AzureADUser -ObjectId $guestKey
```

Resulting error:

```
Remove-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing RemoveUser
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
RequestId: fa05248f-60be-48fa-8ef5-7a381f6e61dd
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 13 Jun 2019 18:15:52 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At C:\Scripts\disable-inactive-guests.ps1:116 char:9
+         Remove-AzureADUser -ObjectId $guestKey
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-AzureADUser], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.RemoveUser
```

Permissions I've added so far... guessing my way through it:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#permissions

Comment: @juunas - thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that link documents the API permissions needed for the Microsoft Graph API rather than AAD Powershell. I figure AAD Powershell is using Graph under the covers, but as far as I can tell, it uses the legacy Azure AD Graph (not Microsoft Graph). I'll add a list (above) of all the permissions I've added so far.

Comment: Could it solve your issue? If my reply is helpful, please accept it to help others, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `Directory.ReadWrite.All` of Azure AD Graph API does not have permission to remove the user.

***Solution*:**

To fix the issue, you need to assign your *service principal* to a directory role e.g. `User administrator`/ `Global administrator`.

Under the deleted reply, I see your comment:

> You cannot grant directory roles to service principals. It has to be API permissions.

No, actually we can grant directory role to service principal.

Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the Azure portal -> `Roles and administrators` -> click `User administrator` or `Global administrator` -> `Add assignment` -> search by your service principal name(must search) -> find it and select it -> click `Select`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect i've found my answer int the [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes#directoryreadwriteall-privileges-detail) and [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#directory-permissions) docs which both seem to go out of their way to state that the **Directory.ReadWrite.All** permission, which would seem to be the most potent, includes "**No rights to delete entities (including users or groups)**".

Sigh...

I think I'll have to do this with a service account (actual Azure AD user account) that has a suitable directory role and authenticate with user/password. I'd really prefer have my batch scripts use certificate auth...